# Choppy playback after rendering in Premier Pro CC

Tags: video, premiere, editing, post-production, playback

I am editing a music video and after I rendered the workspace, I began previewing the video...

In several places the video has become very choppy, skipping frames or something. How do I fix this? Should I play around with playback timing or fps? No clue what to do..

Any help is much appreciated!

Navi

Comment: More information required. Is your render choppy? Is your time line choppy in those areas before rendering? Did you disable any effects while editing and enable them before rendering? Have you tried clearing you cache?

Comment: Do your system specs meet Adobe's minimum requirements? https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is to determine whether the choppiness is due to a bad source (your camera skipped some frames) or an inadequate playback system (your editor is demanding more from your hardware (most likely disk subsystem or GPU) than it can provide).  To do this, render out a small version of the video (such as 360p) and see whether that plays back with or without glitches.  If the render has glitches, you have a bad source file and fixing it will be very hard to do.  If that render plays back without glitches, the problem is likely that your hardware is not powerful enough to edit video as is.  In that case, you can try editing proxies, which are basically smaller versions of your original files.  Once you have all the edit decisions made, you can render out a full-res version.  But it still may not play back without glitches unless you have a good disk subsystem and a sufficiently powerful CPU/GPU.

To test the speed of your hard drive system (and to see what video specs it can support without glitching), run the Blackmagic Design Disk Speed Test (if you have a Mac): https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12 .  Or equivalent if you don't.

Comment: If the original video plays smoothly in all video players and the resulting video after importing it into Premiere and exporting to any video format and/or bitrate is very choppy, then the problem is Premiere. Especially when everything is OK in case of re-encoding the original video before importing it into Premiere using some free video converter.